# Pandas - Writing a Change Log Between Multiple Dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, logging

I am trying to think of the most efficient way to write a change log for large dataframes.  I have thousands of dataframes that have one million rows and 20 column, so efficiency is paramount.  I have a couple solutions for checking for differences between two dataframes, but I cannot figure out the best way to log the changes.  Skeleton algorithm is:

1. Load df1 and df2 into memory.
2. Initialize df3 as df1--this is the baseline (first date with database)
3. Compare df1 and df2 using df1.ne(df2)
4. Write cells with changes to df3 (a merge of some kind...a merge and lamda ops? and df restructuring?)
5. Set df1=df2
6. Loop to next file and load new df2 for comparison
7. Loop to end
8. Write df3 to new file (xlsx, csv, etc.)

I believe I'm stuck on steps 3 and 4.  I figure I need to merge the masked dataframe to the df3 dataframe and then do some kind of operation to concatenate the strings.  Anyone have any ideas?

I have tried the below inside a loop to change df1 and df2, but obtained an incorrect result:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['blue', 2, 3, 4], 'Col2' : [90, 99, 3, 97], 'Col3' : [11, 12, 13, 14]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['blue', 2, 6], 'Col2' : [90, 99, 99], 'Col3' : [11, 12, 13]})
df3=df1
mask=df2.ne(df1)
#This is where trouble begins...df3 is overwritten so the log is only for this one comparison...
#How do I merge the data into df3 so that df3 has the string from df3 and the additions from df2.ne(df1)
df3=(df3.astype(str)[mask] + ' changed to: ' + df2.astype(str)[mask]).fillna(df2.astype(str)).fillna('Removed')
```

Thanks!